File Created by File.WriteAllBytes() Doesn't Persist After Program Ends
I followed an old sqlite-net-pcl tutorial (if you're curious) that used this code to copy an Embedded Resource into an external file it should create in C://Users/my user/AppData/Local. I confirmed the database itself was copied correctly with the GetObject function and that the filepath was where I thought it was, but once the program finishes running, there is no new file there. Am I just fundamentally misunderstanding what is going on?
MainPage.xaml.cs:
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Reflection;
using TestApp.Models;

namespace TestApp
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var assembly = IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo(typeof(App)).Assembly;
            using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("TestApp.Inventory.db"))
            {
                using (MemoryStream MemStr = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    stream.CopyTo(MemStr);
                    File.WriteAllBytes(ObjectRepository.DbPath, MemStr.ToArray());
                }
            }

            ObjectRepository repository = new ObjectRepository();
            foreach (var object in repository.List())
            {
                Objects.Add(object);
            }
         }
    }
}

ObjectRepository.cs:
using System.Reflection;
using TestApp.Models;

namespace TestApp.Data
{
    public class ObjectRepository
    {
        private readonly SQLiteConnection _Database;

        public static string DbPath { get; } = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "Inventory.db");

        public ObjectRepository()
        {
            _Database = new SQLiteConnection(DbPath);
            _Database.CreateTable<Object>();
        }
        public Object GetObject(string ObjectNumber)
        {
            return _Database.FindWithQuery<Object>("select * from Objects where ObjectNumber = ?", [ObjectNumber]);
        }
    }
}

The Object class in TestApp/Models/Object.cs:
using SQLite;

namespace TestApp.Models
{
    [Table("Objects")]
    public class Object
    {
        [PrimaryKey]
        public string ObjectNumber { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }
}


What is the exact value of ObjectRepository.DbPath? Of MemStr.ToArray().Length?

"C:\Users\my name\AppData\Local\Inventory.db" and 20480 respectively.

I called repository.GetObject(testValue); with the ObjectNumber of the test Object I inserted into the database file prior and got the correct data out of it. I do not call File.Delete anywhere in my code.

Open a command prompt. cd c:\  then ENTER. dir Inventory.db /s then ENTER. What is displayed? What folders is that file in?

Are you sure your web page isn't crashing because app pool accounts don't have permission to write to disk outside the web app's folder?

Besides, MainPage itself deletes whatever was stored in that path, every time it's opened

I cannot confirm that it writes the file beyond the correct data being called out of the file path. At no point in time does it ever show up. That's kind of half my problem here, lol. It's also not a webpage, it's a MAUI app.
Edit: Permissions were checked and taken care of.

And that MAUI app deletes the database every time MainPage is opened. If you want to deploy a SQLite database and keep the data from one execution to the next, include the .db file as Content and deploy it to the correct path.

I cannot confirm that it writes the file beyond the correct data being called out of the file path. I suspect you are being impacted by some form of file path virtualisation. The file is clearly somewhere. You just need to find where it is.

If you write some data to the database in the app, then close and reopen the app, is the new data you wrote still there?

@mjwills ooh, I think it's going to deeper into Local than it tells me it does? There's an instance in Packages\com.companyname.testapp_\Localcache\Local. That might be what's going on, thank you!

On a side note: this is inefficient. You don't need the memory stream, you can just do using var fs = File.Open(ObjectRepository.DbPath); stream.CopyTo(fs);

@Charlieface switching to that code does not work, at it runs parallel to the rest of the Main Page initializer and so the ObjectRepository tries to open the file before it is successfully created. It would have to be moved to a function which can be made asynchronous.

There is no async code in there, I used CopyTo not CopyToAsync... whether there should be is a different question and probably requires restructuring your code significantly as you can't have async constructors.

Ah. In my arrogance, I just called File.Open inside the stream.CopyTo function call and that seems to have been the cause of the issue.

The simple answer is that the file actually was being created, just not where I thought it was based on the used file path.
Saving directly in the AppData/Local folder seems to not be possible, and when checking where a file ends up, checking the base path alone fed into the File object does not guarantee filepath accuracy.

Try setting the property Position of the memory stream to 0 before copying the stream to the file.
MemStr.Position = 0;
File.WriteAllBytes(ObjectRepository.DbPath, MemStr.ToArray());


ToArray is being used here, so not relevant. (It's inefficient but it works).
